# Why does it crash while sending Bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to share an image by sending a Bitmap. The solution i found works on the emulator for Android 10.0 but not on Android 7.0 (neither on my LG V20 running Android 9) where it crashes.

Here is my current code. Any idea how to avoid the crash? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
            picIV.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = picIV.getDrawingCache();

            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
            bitmap, "Challengers", null);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I found something cool!");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Design!"));
```

The crash seems to be happenning when running this line

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `path` is `null`? Did you debug it?

From the source of the method `Uri.parse(...)` I noticed that it returns an error if it takes `null` as an argument and `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(...)` returns `null` "if the image failed to be stored for any reason".

Comment: Seems like you are right, path is null. Not sure why. Any idea how to make it not null?

Answer (score 0):

Found another method that worked on Android 7 but not on Android 10. So found out a way to make them work together.

```
                Uri uri;
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Challengers", null);

                if (path!=null) {
                    uri = Uri.parse(path);
                }else{
                    uri = null;
                    String string="" ;
                    try {
                        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "to-share.png");
                        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                        stream.close();
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(string, "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I found something cool!");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Design!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work across each API -- Answer is in Koltin

1. Create `Bitmap` From `View`

   ```
   fun createBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
           val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, 
           view.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
           val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
           view.layout(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
           view.draw(canvas)
           return bitmap
       }
   ```
2. Create a `File` for saving the `Bitmap`

   ```
   fun getFileFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): File? {
   val parentDirectory = File(externalCacheDir, "reminder_images")  //image file is stored in external cache directory/reminder_images
   if (!parentDirectory.exists()) {
       parentDirectory.mkdirs()
   }
   val externalCacheFile = File(parentDirectory, "name_of_your_file.png")
   return writeBitmapToFile(externalCacheFile, bitmap)
   ```

   }
3. Write the `Bitmap` to `File` using `Stream`

   ```
   fun writeBitmapToFile(externalCacheFile: File, bitmap: Bitmap): File? {
       return try {
           val fOut = FileOutputStream(externalCacheFile)
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut)
           fOut.flush()
           fOut.close()
           externalCacheFile
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           null
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create the `FileProvider` in Manifest

   ```
            <provider
               android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
               android:authorities="com.your_package_name.FileProvider"
               android:exported="false"
               android:grantUriPermissions="true">
               <meta-data
                   android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                   android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
           </provider>
   ```
5. 5.Create the `provider_paths.xml` resource file

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
     </paths>
   ```
6. Get `Uri` From `File` using `FileProvider`

   ```
   val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.your_package_name.FileProvider", externalCacheFile)
   ```

Once you have the `Uri` of the image file share the file as you were doing earlier using `Intent`.

In my solution, the image file is stored in app-specific external directories. This image file would be deleted if your app is uninstalled. If you want some other behaviour please check [data-storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

Comment: Thanks for the code.
I'm trying to put it into Java, struggling with the "context" on the last line. Any suggestion?

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.your_package_name.FileProvider", externalCacheFile)` if your writing above line in `Activity` you can simply replace `context`  with `this`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I still cant get it to run. `this` and `context` create an error in the code. what i has is `Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.blanknewapp.FileProvider", externalCacheFile);`
The error i get is `Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.blanknewapp.FileProvider`

Comment: Make sure  android:authorities="com.example.blanknewapp.FileProvider"  of your provider in Manifest is exactly matching the  "com.example.blanknewapp.FileProvider" in yours`getUriForFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. It was the permissions. Even though i had put the permissions in the Manifest.xml also need to add a couple lines in onCreate.

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},requestCode);
    onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},grantResults);
```

Thanks everyone for your answers, really helpful!